# Detail button doesn't show up on detail page

Tags: custom-button

I have created a detail button which, when clicked navigates to the create new object page. It is defined as follows:

```
* Display Type: Detail Page Button
* Behaviour: Display in New Window
* Content Source: URL
* "/{!$ObjectType.Contracts__c}/e"
```

I have added the button into the custom buttons section on the page layout. When I open the object however, the button does not appear? Have I missed something? Tia.

EDIT:
Here are some screenshots:

1) I have added the detail button "New ERN" to the page layout. I have definitely saved it, and there is only 1 page layout.
[image: Page Layout]

2) When I now navigate to my detail page, there is no detail button!!
[image: Detail Page]

I really don't understand why. The object that I am adding the detail button to is a junction object... but it shouldn't really have anything to do with that, right?

Comment: Is there more than one layout for this object? And I presume the view action hasn't been overridden with a Visualforce page?

Comment: No, there is only one layout, and I have no visualforce pages.

Comment: These buttons only show when the page is viewed and not when the page is being edited. Is the problem that you want a button or link showing when the page is in edit mode? Perhaps a new question asking "How to provide a "New" option for a lookup field in layout-based UI" with your screen shots would be clearer.

Comment: Is your SObject really called `Contracts__c` (that is plural)? Normally, Sobject name is singular as one instance represents a single Order, Contract, Account, Contact, Quote, Foo, etc.

Comment: In your second screenshot, you have the `Save`, `Save & New`, and `Cancel` buttons present. Seeing this, I'm going to assume you are editing the record. Custom buttons will not show up on a standard record edit page. I don't believe, or better yet, don't know a way to add custom buttons to the edit page

Comment: Second screenshot that you added is for new record. When you hit save button and detail page has open then your button has displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually when the record is saved that means it shows the button in detail page if it is missed then check once again and do the process clearly in page layout and save it not do quick save do full save it definitely shows ...........!

Comment: Hello, I have now added screenshots. I have definitely saved the layout and I only have one layout, so really don't understand why it doesn't show!

Answer (score 0):

Second screenshot that you displayed is of New Records. It is not detail page. New button that you added is displayed when you save the record and new window opens.